# Can't open modal using `trigger_id` from Slash Command in Slack Bot

Tags: node.js, express, slack-api, slack-block-kit, slack-dialog

My goal is to trigger modal open using Slack slash command.
I got the `trigger_id` from the slash command in my slack app, and trying to open modal using it, but getting following error though I can see valid `trigger_id` in my console logs.

```
Error in trigger handler Error: An API error occurred: invalid_trigger_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of my bad.
I used `push` method instead of `open` method to open modal.
It is working after changing my code like this:

```
await bot.api.views.open({
    trigger_id: triggerId //You can get from slash command payload,
    view: view // this is the modal content view
})
```